# Get VsCode IDE support for css modules?

Tags: visual-studio-code, css-modules

Gatsby supports css modules out of the box. However, VsCode does not. This results in:

1. lack of type completion for CSS module imports
2. A red line underneath the css module name because the VsCode Typescript compiler cannot find `page.module.css`

For example, there is no completion in the following code and the import is underlined in red

```js
import styles from './componentName.module.css'
```

How do I get my IDE to support css modules?

This is different from getting my code to compile. It already compiles because Gatsby supports css modules, I just need my IDE to recognize them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `const styles = require('./componentName.module.css');`